# How to simulate Subqueries in the ON Clause in Vertica database?

Tags: join, subquery, vertica

Hy everbody , i am having some trouble in transforming a query that has a set of subqueries in the ON clause.
 The initial code was created in SQL Server and i have changed to work on Vertica.

This is the code :

```
    SELECT
    DISTINCT DocFinanceiro.AutoId AS AutoId,
    DocFinanceiro.Classe AS ClasseDoc,
    EspecPrestador.Seq AS Sequencia,
    PrestadorServico.Codigo AS CodigoPrest,
    PessoaPrest.Nome AS NomePrestador,
    DocFinanceiro.CompFinanceira AS CompFinanceira,
    EspecialidadeServico.Nome AS Especialidade,
    ClassePrestador.Nome AS ClsPrestador,
    RegistroPessoa.Numero AS RegistroINSS,
    RegistroPessoa.Tipo AS TipoRegPessoa,
    DocFinanceiro.DataVencimento AS DataVencimentoDocFin
    FROM DocFinanceiro 
    INNER JOIN ClasseDocFinanceiro
    ON DocFinanceiro.Classe = ClasseDocFinanceiro.Codigo
    INNER JOIN ItemFinanceiro  ON DocFinanceiro.AutoId = ItemFinanceiro.Documento
    INNER JOIN ClasseApropriacaoFinan
    ON ItemFinanceiro.ClasseApro = ClasseApropriacaoFinan.Codigo
    INNER JOIN ContratoFinanceiro
    ON DocFinanceiro.ContratoFinanceiro = ContratoFinanceiro.AutoId
    INNER JOIN Pessoa  ON ContratoFinanceiro.Pessoa = Pessoa.AutoId
    INNER JOIN GeradorItemFinan
    ON ItemFinanceiro.AutoId = GeradorItemFinan.ItemFinan
    INNER JOIN PrestadorServico
    ON ContratoFinanceiro.AutoId = PrestadorServico.ContratoFinanceiro
    INNER JOIN Pessoa PessoaPrest  ON PrestadorServico.Pessoa = PessoaPrest.AutoId
    INNER JOIN TipoValorFinan
    ON ClasseApropriacaoFinan.TipoValor = TipoValorFinan.Codigo
    INNER JOIN ClasseContratoFinanceiro
    ON ContratoFinanceiro.Classe = ClasseContratoFinanceiro.AutoId
    INNER JOIN ClassePrestador
    ON PrestadorServico.Classe = ClassePrestador.Codigo
    LEFT JOIN EspecPrestador
    ON EspecPrestador.Prestador = PrestadorServico.AutoId
    AND EspecPrestador.Seq = 1
    LEFT JOIN EspecialidadeServico
    ON EspecialidadeServico.AutoId = EspecPrestador.Especialidade
    LEFT JOIN RegistroPessoa ON PessoaPrest.AutoId = RegistroPessoa.Pessoa
--This is the part where i getr stuck    
AND
    (
       RegistroPessoa.AutoId =
       (
          SELECT
          RegistroPessoa.AutoId
          FROM RegistroPessoa
          WHERE RegistroPessoa.Pessoa = PessoaPrest.Autoid
          AND (RegistroPessoa.Tipo = 1 OR RegistroPessoa.Tipo = 1) order by 1  limit 1
       )
    )
--until here
    WHERE (GeradorItemFinan.TipoGerador = 1)
    AND (DocFinanceiro.CompFinanceira = 1)
    AND (PrestadorServico.AutoId = 1)
    AND DocFinanceiro.CompSeq = 1
    AND (DocFinanceiro.Numero IS NOT NULL)
    AND (DocFinanceiro.Classe <> 1)
    ORDER BY AutoId, Sequencia
    ;
```

**If anybody has any ideas it would be great !!**

Comment: he "IN" clause will work only when i have usded with WHERE condition!!! It does not seem to work when used with "ON" Error: [Vertica][VJDBC](4816) ERROR: Subqueries in the ON clause are not supported SQLState: 0A000 ErrorCode: 4816 –

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get this:
    
    AND (RegistroPessoa.Tipo = 1 OR RegistroPessoa.Tipo = 1)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this part! The subquery work perfectly as it is !

Comment: Ohhh the values in there are notthe real ones :) sorry the 1 value was alterd by me before i have put the query online :)

Answer (score 0):

try replace

RegistroPessoa.AutoId = (SELECT...)

to
 RegistroPessoa.AutoId IN (SELECT...)

and use  aliases for table short names

Comment: The "IN" clause will work only when i have usded with WHERE condition!!! It does not seem to work when used with "ON" Error: [Vertica][VJDBC](4816) ERROR: Subqueries in the ON clause are not supported
SQLState:  0A000
ErrorCode: 4816